# sync cookies between webview and java

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I am almost dead doing this.Need help.

**My Requirement** :-

I am developing an android app and want to *use the cookies(/session) from webview in my java* code. I basically want to get the *html of other pages of an url after login* in webview without opening those pages in webview but through my java code.

**What I tried** :-

For this I tried `HttpClient` and `HttpURLConnection` referring many SO questions but failed.

Can anybody please give me a sample code?

Say I have cookies in a hashmap cookies. How Can I use `HttpClient` and `HttpURLConnection` or anything else to get the other page `html`. The website I am trying with is **`https:`**

Please give a sample code

Comment: Are you able to read the Cookie with the session-id by JavaScript in your WebView? By default these Session-Cookies are marked "HttpOnly" when created server-side, so it should not be possible to get the values by script. Try to execute `console.log(document.cookie)` in your WebView and watch LogCat. Can you see the SessionId?

Comment: @hgoebl we can get the httponly cookies also by CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("url")

Comment: So where is the problem? Take the cookie and [set the header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie).

Comment: i need url of other pages of logged in website without opening in webview...using urlconnection by getting the html of other page....how to set the cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am right u are trying to use your webview's cookies to get other pages of site in your activity java code.if yes try this:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    URL url2 = new URL("url");
    URLConnection con = (URLConnection) url2.openConnection();
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie",CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("logged in url in webview"));
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.connect();

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    StringBiffer html;
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        html.append(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the cookie as a HTTP header? I am not sure if I have understood you right but you can consider these:

- Cookies: If you want to load some resource (no matter if it is a web page, image, css, js or something else) you are making a HTTP request. If the server keeps a session for your user, you are probably given a session cookie. The cookie must be sent with each request to the server as e COOKIE header. So if you want to pass the cookie to your request, add it as a header. Android provides you an easy way to do this with the `CookieManager` class. You can refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).
- SSL: If you are trying to access a secured web site (https) you have to use an SSL certificate. Android comes up with a bunch of predistributed certificates for most of the popular web cites (e.g Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc.). You can use them out of the box. If your SSL certificate is not presented, you have to add it manually. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) for more information.

I hope this was useful :)